# Диаграмма для JSR223 Sampler в Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jsr223

Есть ли возможность (и есть ли есть, то каким путём) реализовав определённую логику в своём JSR223 Sampler, прикрутить какой-либо Listener с наличием диаграммы (chart) для визуализации?

Возможно, необходимо как-то использовать JSR223 Listener? Возможно ещё какие-либо варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Для визуализации чего?

Если ваш JSR223 Sampler считает какое-то числовое значение - вы можете положить его в переменную JMeter

```
def myValue = 42
vars.put('ts-hit', myValue as String)
```

затем добавьте в user.properties строчки:

```
sample_variables=ts-hit
```

и

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=Chunk Hit
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=Number of Hits
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=ts-hit
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=Number of Hits :
```

в следующий раз когда вы запустите тест и сгенерируете HTML Reporting Dashboard - там будет дополнительный график со значениями переменной `ts-hit` в течение времени теста

Полезные ссылки:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)